# element is not working with arrow function to route Home Component In react Router V6

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am Route the home component when initially on local host using render with arrow function.My Router V6 is not accepting element to route the  Component
My Code is

```
<Route path="*"
          exact
          render={()=>{
            return element={<Home/>} />
          }}
          
          />
```

When I am using <Route path="*" element={}/> It works fine but when I use render method to return the Home component then it generates error in element={} with return statement.
Please help me to correct the syntax.

Comment: The syntax you used when it works fine is the correct syntax to use.

Answer (score 0):

According to `react-router-dom` [official document](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route),

You just do like that.

```
<Route path="*" element={<Home />} />
```